# Set an attribute for a loop which is inside another loop

Tags: php

first loop which will be create a html and second loop will be create image links, I'm using Lightbox2 plugin to show the images in lightbox gallery.

If each image has same attribute the plugin will be load all of them as a one gallery, but if has different attribute it will show them as a single image.

So what i want is to set a unique attribute for each loop.
That's what i did is here:

```
<?  while ( has_sub_field('info') ) : 
    $j = 0;
?>
<li>        
    <div class="thumbs">

    <? while( have_rows('images') ): the_row(); ?>

    <a data-lightbox="building-<?= $j++ ?>" href="<?php echo $image_full_url; ?>" 
       title="<? echo $attachment->post_excerpt ?>">
        <div id="aks"><img src="<?php echo $image_url; ?>"></div>
    </a>

    <? endwhile ?>
    </div>
</li>
<? endwhile ?>
```

As you can see i set the attribute to `data-lightbox="building-<?= $j++ ?>"` but it is giving me different value for each image.

Where i should define the `$j`, so each group of image has different attribute?

Comment: Of course it's giving you different values for each image!  You're doing `$j++`.  This increments `$j` and returns the original value.

Comment: Put `$j=0` before `while ( has_sub_field('info') ) :`, use `$j` in `"building-<?= $j ?>"` and then increment (`$j++`) after the first `<? endwhile ?>` but before the last `<? endwhile ?>`.

Comment: @Sean What should be the code after first endwhile? i got confused

Comment: <? endwhile ?> <? $j++ ?>
    </div>

Comment: Your `$j` increment can be anywhere between the endwhiles, ie. `<? endwhile ?><? $j++; ?></div></li><? endwhile ?>` or `<? endwhile ?></div><? $j++; ?></li><? endwhile ?>` or `<? endwhile ?></div></li><? $j++; ?><? endwhile ?>` or `<? endwhile ?></div></li><? $j++; endwhile ?>`, etc.